# Issue while reading data list considers as next item if data has comma inside

Tags: python, list, opencsv

I am reading a csv file using csv reader. and then using for loop I iterate and get the records in list . Now as my data has comma (amount values-0,00),its Dutch format, Now  during the read after as there is comma in string , it considers it as another string. How to include all the data in single string?

example- data am reading

```
21RE-R01ER3100000*
21RE-R01SR5100000*
21RE-R01IT5100155 XX.XX.XX.XXXXXBankspaar Hypotheek                                        0,00-              8.500,00                                                     *
21RE-R01IT5100155 XX.XX.XX.XXXXX8Bankspaar Hypotheek                                        0,00-              8.500,00    
Till * is the and of line  
CODE-
                                               *
```

Comment: Try setting delimiter as space.

Comment: If you need each line in a single record with 1 column, you don't need csv reader, you can try normal file read.

Comment: Thank you for your response
I am reading 7GB file that's the reason I opted CSV reader , normal way its taking lot of time.by keeping delimiter as space still didn't help me moreover using this comma is removed from data
sample code-
for row in reader:
  if any(x.strip() for x in row):
    if row[0].startswith ('21XXXEOD'):  
        str_array.extend(row)
        fino_content_list.append(' '.join(str_array))
        str_array = []
    else: 
        str_array.extend(row)

Comment: If this is the program you use, if you use `str_array.extend(",".join(row))` instead of `str_array.extend(row)` should solve your issue, as your file is not really a comma separated file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_array.extend(row)`  solved the issue